# Custom actions for a content type but not one of its childen

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am creating an Item in my dropdown to go to an application page I created. The option in the dropdown is added to the context menu for items with spesified content types. However, i seam to have hit a small snag.

```
<CustomAction Id="UserInterfaceCustomActions.DocumentMigrateToLocation"
RegistrationType="ContentType"
RegistrationId="0x0101"
Location="EditControlBlock"
Sequence="500"
Title="Migrate document to location">
<UrlAction Url="~sitecollection/_layouts/ContentMigrationTool.aspx?listId={ListId}&amp;ItemId={ItemId}"/>
```

This added an option to the menu for all Document content types (0x0101 + children). This is perfect, because I need the option on word documents. Unfortunatly I don't want the option to be on lets say a Picture content type (0x010102).

How can I have the option available for word documents (0x0101) and not on some of its children content types (Ex.: 0x010102)?

Thank you in advance,
Edouard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking you have a couple options, given that you aren't given much flexibility when it's an ECB CustomAction:

1. Explicitly define a CustomAction for *all* Document & descendant content types except for Pictures.
2. Some kind of craziness involving creating another CustomAction, this time with a ControlAssembly/Class, which checks the content type of SPContext.Current.List, and emits JavaScript to hide all links containing the above href if it's a Picture library.

Other than that I'm afraid I'm drawing blanks

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
We are now thinking of using the List RegistrationType to work around this small issue. Out of curiosity, how would I go about doing number one that you mentioned? Number two is definatly crazy, but still possible.